Error: No named parameter with the name 'maxFacetHits'. With Algolia Search
I have no idea what is going on. Tried to build my flutter project today and I can not get it to run on either Android or iOS simulator. I get this error each time:
Error (Xcode): ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/algolia_helper_flutter-1.1.0/lib/src/service/algolia_client_extensions.dart:41:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'maxFacetHits'.

Here is my flutter doctor:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.27.0, on macOS 15.1.1 24B91 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.96.0)
[✓] Connected device (5 available)
[✓] Network resources

I have tried running flutter clean, flutter pub get multiple times but still keep getting the issue over and over again.
My Algolia Version is:

algolia_helper_flutter: 1.1.0
algolia_insights: 1.0.1


Looks like its a known bug: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-flutter/issues/151

There is no official solution for now yet..but there is a work around.. you just have to add this to your pubspec.yaml
dependency_overrides:
  algolia_client_core: 1.27.1
  algolia_client_insights: 1.27.1
  algolia_client_search: 1.27.1
  algoliasearch: 1.27.1

Please see the original post on Github
